# Bash: How to append a range of lines from a file to another

Tags: text-processing

Let's say I have file contents similar to the following (fileA):

```
lorem.ipsum=dolor sit amet.
donec.non.nibh=ut tortor
nam.mattis.lacus=et rhoncus sodales
get.placerat=neque fringilla.
```

What are the appropriate commands to get lines 2-3 to another file?

I tried `cat`'ing file contents piped to `grep` with `-A` switch but this isn't exactly what I want as it depends on the pattern, not line number:

```
cat fileA | grep -A1 "^donec" >> fileB
```

fileB contents:

```
donec.non.nibh=ut tortor
nam.mattis.lacus=et rhoncus sodales
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use sed to `p`rint a range selection (from 2 to 3):

```
~$ sed -n '2,3p' fileA
donec.non.nibh=ut tortor
nam.mattis.lacus=et rhoncus sodales
```

or use head to select the first 3 lines, and tail to select the last 2 lines (of the 3 lines):

```
~$ head -3 fileA | tail -2
donec.non.nibh=ut tortor
nam.mattis.lacus=et rhoncus sodales
```

Comment: Thanks! Thought I'd share for anyone wanting to use the head-tail -method that using an arithmetic expression might be helpful as you don't need to calculate yourself:
`head -34 fileA | tail -$((34-6+1))` ==> Gets you lines 6-34 from fileA.